# Computing gradients of intermediate nodes in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to learn how autograd works in PyTorch. In the simple program below, I don't understand why gradients of `loss` w.r.t `W1` and `W2` are `None`.  <strike>As far as I understand from the documentation, `W1` and `W2` are volatile, therefore gradients cannot be computed.</strike>  Is that it? I mean, how I cannot take derivative of the loss w.r.t intermediate nodes? Can anyone explain me what I am missing here?

```
import torch
import torch.autograd as tau

W = tau.Variable(torch.FloatTensor([[0, 1]]), requires_grad=True)
a = tau.Variable(torch.FloatTensor([[2, 2]]), requires_grad=False)
b = tau.Variable(torch.FloatTensor([[3, 3]]), requires_grad=False)

W1 = W  + a * a
W2 = W1 - b * b * b
Z = W2 * W2

print 'W:', W
print 'W1:', W1
print 'W2:', W2
print 'Z:', Z

loss = torch.sum((Z - 3) * (Z - 3))
print 'loss:', loss

# free W gradient buffer in case you are running this cell more than 2 times
if W.grad is not None: W.grad.data.zero_()

loss.backward()
print 'W.grad:', W.grad

# all of them are None
print 'W1.grad:', W1.grad
print 'W2.grad:', W2.grad
print 'a.grad:', a.grad
print 'b.grad:', b.grad
print 'Z.grad:', Z.grad
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When required, intermediate gradients are accumulated [in a C++ buffer](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/csrc/autograd/input_buffer.h) but in order to save memory they are not retained by default (exposed in python object).
Only gradients of leaf Variables set with `requires_grad=True` will be retained (so `W`in your example)

One way to retain intermediate gradients is to register a hook. One hook for this job is `retain_grad()` ([see PR](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/2199/files))
In your example, if you write `W2.retain_grad()`, intermediate gradient of `W2` will be exposed in `W2.grad`

`W1` and `W2` are not volatile (you can check by accessing their `volatile` attribute (ie: `W1.volatile`)) and cannot be because they are not leaf variables (such as `W`, `a` and `b`). On the contrary, the computation of their gradients is required, see their `requires_grad` attribute.
If only one leaf variable is `volatile`, the whole **backward graph is not constructed** (You can check by making a volatile and look at the loss gradient function)

```
a = tau.Variable(torch.FloatTensor([[2, 2]]), volatile=True)
# ...
assert loss.grad_fn is None
```

To sum up

- **Volatility** implies no gradient computation: Useful in inference mode

  - Only one leaf variable set volatile **disable** gradient computation
- **Requiring gradients** implies gradient computation. Intermediate ones are exposed or not

  - Only one leaf variable requiring grad **enable** gradient computation

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's much more clear now.

Comment: Hi, which pytorch version is that? In 0.3 and 0.4 even if I set `W2.retain_grad=True`, I don't get `W2.grad`.

Comment: Hi, I think it was v0.3. In order to retain an intermediate gradient on W2, have you tried to init the `W` variable with `requires_grad=True` (as in OP' question) and to **call** `retain_grad()` on `W2` ? (Also, setting `W2.retain_grad` to `True` will override the method aiming at effectively retaining the gradient through a hook)